# Integration Testing Umbraco

Tags: integration-testing, umbraco, data-access-layer

So I have written a fairly simple DataAccess Layer for use with Umbraco CMS 4.9. I want to write some Integration tests to test that my repositories work etc.

Obviously Umbraco has some dependencies, so how do people test that their data access works normally?

p.s We already have BDD / selenium tests..I want proper Nunit Integration tests...

Comment: What I ended up doing here is writing a provider model so that if my DAL has a httpcontext, then I do the nomral new Node(id) method to get content. If I don't have a context, I call the webservice to get the content. It's slow, but thats not a major problem as it is an integration test.

Answer (score 0):

One approach might be to fake the source data, i.e. the nodes themselves. Obviously it would be a fair bit of work to set up a data tree, but because the Node object inherits from INode, you should be able to inject your own object implementing INode and create your own data tree for all the unit tests to use.